# Using Xamarin on macOS-13 Azure DevOps Build Agents

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Following the announcement by Microsoft that Xamarin will now support iOS 17 and Android 14 we are now looking to build our Xamarin based app in AzureDevOps on macOS-13 build agents (this agent is required since targeting iOS 17 requires XCode 15).

As indicated by this post the Xamarin tooling isn't currently installed on the macOS-13 agent (and there seems to be reluctance on Microsofts part to install them): https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/8647

There is mention in that post of using homebrew to install Xamarin. Is anyone able to confirm that this is as simple as running commands such as `brew install --cask xamarin-ios`?

We are aware that Xamarin is end of life and are planning to migrate however we still want to be able to build the current app against latest OS versions while its supported.

Answer (score 3):

> Is anyone able to confirm that this is as simple as running commands such as brew install --cask xamarin-ios?

Yes. You can use the Bash task to run the **brew install --cask xamarin-ios** to install the xamarin components. Then you can use the Xamarin task to build your project.

Here is the YAML example:

```
steps:
- bash: 'brew install --cask xamarin-ios'
  displayName: 'Bash Script'

- task: XamariniOS@2
  displayName: 'Build Xamarin.iOS solution AwesomeApp/AwesomeApp.iOS/AwesomeApp.iOS.csproj'
  inputs:
    solutionFile: AwesomeApp/AwesomeApp.iOS/AwesomeApp.iOS.csproj
```

Then Xamarin task will get the required targets when building.

To use Xamarin.Android, you can use the commnad: `brew install --cask xamarin-android`